# Bootstrap 4 navbar overlap not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, overlap, bootstrap-4

Hi i'm triying to put mi navbar over an image in bootstrap 4...I don't know why it's not working I already set css properties to both elements but nothing happens...here is my code:

```
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
              <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                          <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                          </li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
        </nav>

        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1347-640-8.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
  </header>
```

CSS

```
 nav{
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 10 ;
    background-color: transparent;
   }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that CSS? Remove the CSS and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to make something like this. take a look on css I have added a extra class on that image class overimg. If you have any question ask me in comment. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/448ruuct/)

```css
.overimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative; /*By default its relative*/
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.7;/*Set this opacity for a visiable background through navbar*/
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-rr9hHBQ43H7HSOmmNkxzQGazS/Khx+L8ZRHteEY1tQ4=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-+kIbbrvS+0dNOjhmQJzmwe/RILR/8lb/+4+PUNVW09k=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1347-640-8.jpg" class="img-fluid overimg" alt="Responsive image" />
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, but its a little hard to know if this will work for you because you have not provided the proper context to answer the question.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

```
<style>
nav {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}
</style>

<header>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1347-640-8.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your issue.  This way the image will always be behind the nav and the nav (collapsed or not) will overlap:

I removed your `position: absolute;` from the nav and put it on the image instead.

```
.background-image {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Then I added that `.background-image` class to the image.  See my working codepen here:

http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/JEKrNb